# Check Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: bash, mount

I am wanting to monitor whether a directory's transport is connected with bash.

I currently have the shell:

```
#!/bin/bash

mounts=('/mount1' '/mount2' '/mount3' '/mount4' '/HDD');

for mount in "${mounts[@]}"
do
    if grep -qs ${mount} /proc/mounts
    then 
        echo "${mount} is mounted."
    else
        #force remount
        sudo umount -l ${mount}
        sudo fusermount -uz ${mount}
        sudo mount ${mount}

    fi
done
```

but `grep -qs ${mount} /proc/mounts` does not actually check the endpoint? what should I do instead?

Comment: What about this isn't working exactly? Does the contents of `/proc/mounts` change when the endpoint disconnects in the way you intend to detect?

Comment: It does not change. That is the problem

Comment: So then how are you expecting this to work at all? Do you know of something you *can* check that will indicate that the connection has dropped? If you don't/there isn't then that is going to be a problem.